# Dynamics SL: Adding Custom Tables

Tags: t-sql, microsoft-dynamics

So I have been trying to add a custom table to a preexisting screen in Dynamics SL and I can't seem to get anything to work. Currently I have this on the Form_Load event

```
Private Sub Form1_Load()
Call VBA_SetAddr("bSOShipLot_Alias", bSOShipLot_Alias, nSOShipLot_Alias, LenB(bSOShipLot_Alias))
Call SqlCursorEx(CSR_SOShipLot_Alias, NOLEVEL, "CSR_SOShipLot_Alias", "SOShipLot_Alias", "SOShipLot_Alias")
End Sub
```

I try to add a cursor variable to the Module page

```
Public CSR_SOShipLot_Alias As Integer
```

but this just crashes the screen. The documentation for this sort of thing is scarce and I've looked through all the SDK documentation we have and have come up with almost nothing pertaining to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so to add a new table through the customization manager do the following: 
1. Add Module file with setup of the custom table you're trying to add (see below for example)

```
    Option Explicit

Attribute VB_Name = "FCGenKeyValDH"
Type FCGenKeyVal
 Comments            As String * 250
 Crtd_DateTime             As SDate
 Crtd_Prog            As String * 8
 Crtd_User            As String * 10
 Key1            As String * 30
 Key2            As String * 30
 Key3            As String * 30
 LinkedTable            As String * 30
 LUpd_DateTime             As SDate
 LUpd_Prog            As String * 8
 LUpd_User            As String * 10
 Purpose            As String * 30
 Id            As Long
 Status            As String * 1
 User1            As String * 30
 User2            As String * 30
 User3            As Double
 User4            As Double
 User5            As String * 10
 User6            As String * 10
 User7             As SDate
 User8             As SDate
 Value            As String * 30
End Type

Public bFCGenKeyVal As FCGenKeyVal, nFCGenKeyVal As FCGenKeyVal
```

2. on the Form_Load() event add the reference to the buffer table and the SQL cursors

   ```
   Call VBA_SetAddr("bFCGenKeyVal", bFCGenKeyVal, nFCGenKeyVal,LenB(bFCGenKeyVal))
   Call SqlCursorEx(CSR_FCGenKeyVal, NOLEVEL, "CSR_FCGenKeyVal", "FCGenKeyVal", "FCGenKeyVal")
   ```
3. In the declaration file add the cursor variable

   ```
   Public CSR_FCGenKeyVal As Integer
   ```
4. save changes, close screen and reopen. The table should appear in the add object wizard which tells you the custom table is linked to the screen.

Comment: here is an even better resource that walks you through this process. https://www.dslug.com/blogs/mark-schrier/2017/02/27/adding-a-table-extension-to-an-existing-dynamics-sl-screen?AuthToken=vI34zt0kkWScxgTl9ilXJn1x0WIATjOIfvpWtzuRmqnZ8+Kk5ZU8Tw